# Drag item from Listbox and start method on drop into specific Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, drag-and-drop, listbox

I am quite new to C# so please keep things as simple as possible.
My problem is as follows: I have a Listbox to which I add Items dynamically at runtime and I also have four different Canvases within my UI.
Now the user has to be able to drag any Item from the Listbox and drop it into one of the four Canvases.
Upon drop a method will be started which needs to know which Item has been draged and into which Canvas it was dropped.

I have not implemented anything yet but here at least my XAML:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="gridMenu" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Background="#FFE6E6E6">
     <ListBox Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Background="#FFE6E6E6" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Panel.ZIndex="1" PreviewMouseDown="listBox1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <ListBoxItem Content="test1" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="test2" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="test3" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="test4" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="test5" />
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="gridImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" TextBlock.Drop="grid1_Drop">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
        <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" />
        <Canvas Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Drag and Drop isn't an easy topic, so I am afraid I can't make it that simple and I agree with [ekholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436684/ekholm): You will definitely need a decent c#/wpf knowledge to succesfully implement this. Even when you get your code to run you will be stuck when you want to modify/extend your DragDrop Code.

Here's an example to get you started based on your provided markup:

**XAML:**

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="gridImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Canvas Background="LightGreen" AllowDrop="True" Drop="canvasImage_Drop" DragEnter="canvasImage_DragEnter" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />

      <Canvas Background="LightYellow" AllowDrop="True" Drop="canvasImage_Drop" DragEnter="canvasImage_DragEnter"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" />

      <Canvas Background="LightPink" AllowDrop="True" Drop="canvasImage_Drop" DragEnter="canvasImage_DragEnter"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1" />

      <Canvas Background="LightSteelBlue" AllowDrop="True" Drop="canvasImage_Drop" DragEnter="canvasImage_DragEnter"  Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="canvasImage4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
private Point _startPoint;
private static readonly string _dropIdentifier = "dropIdentifier";

private void listBox_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  // The initial mouse position
  _startPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
}

private void listBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  // Get the current mouse position
  Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(null);
  Vector diff = _startPoint - mousePos;

  if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
      (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
      Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
  {
    // Get the dragged ListBoxItem
    var listBox = sender as ListBox;
    var listBoxItem = listBox.SelectedItem;

    // Initialize the drag & drop operation
    DataObject dragData = new DataObject(_dropIdentifier, listBoxItem);
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);
  } 
}

private void canvasImage_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(_dropIdentifier))
  {
    var item = e.Data.GetData(_dropIdentifier) as ListBoxItem;
    DropOnCanvas(sender as Canvas, item);
  }
}

private void canvasImage_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
  if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(_dropIdentifier) ||
    sender == e.Source)
  {
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
  }
}

public void DropOnCanvas(Canvas targetCanvas, ListBoxItem item)
{
  // do your stuff here ...
  int textHeight = 20;
  var text = new TextBlock() { Text = item.Content.ToString(), Height = textHeight };
  Canvas.SetTop(text, targetCanvas.Children.Count * textHeight);
  targetCanvas.Children.Add(text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly.
I know it is difficult without proper C# knowledge. As ekholm suggested I did read his link in detail again and I did make it work but I still had a problem with the DataObject, as I don't directly know what objects have to be used in the method DragDrop.DoDragDrop.
Your code will really help me to know what I still have to learn, I already read a good book on C# basics but I still need to learn how to connect the C# code properly with WPF/XAML and I don't know which book to get.

Comment: When I add items dynamically using fileList.Items.Add("mynewitem");
And try to drop it into the canvas I get an exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

at DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listBox, dragData, DragDropEffects.Move);

Comment: The Drop is expecting a ListBoxItem. But you are adding a string to the listbox items. So either add a ListboxItem  fileList.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem to the ListBox: { Content = "mynewitem" }) or change the Drop method that it can deal with strings and Listboxitems ...

Comment: Thank you! I actually opened another thread for this and got the same answer. I am still learning WPF and there seems to be a lot to learn...

Answer (score 2):

This tutorial should get you started: http://wpftutorial.net/DragAndDrop.html

Comment: I already read about 20 tutorials found on google (including the one on your link) and none of them worked for me, since they expected either too much knowledge on C# or it wasn't for the same situation as mine.
I would very much appreciate a direct answer to my problem.

Comment: I linked to that one since that was were I learned to implement my first drag and drop with WPF, which was actually dragging items from a ListBox to a Canvas, You could actually copy/paste most of of what you need from there. Of course it requires some C# knowledge, but that's going to be hard to avoid all together